# Is multidimension array a good choice for this?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

For my parser i want to (depending on user input) save parse stats for the sites a user chooses to parse.

So lets say the user chooses site A, site B and site D:

I then from my threads want to be able to add different statitsitcs like; links parsed, pages parsed, duplicates found, etc. (so basically int values for the sites).

How would i create this into c#? 
My idea is to make some kind of multidimensional array?

Is there a better way?

Any suggestions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class that encapsulates the statistics and than use a dictionary with a website name as key.

```
public class Statistics
{
    public int PagesParsed { get; set; }
}

var collection = new Dictionary<string, Statistics>();

collection.Add("Site A", new Statistics { PagesParsed = 42 });
var siteAStatistics = collection["Site A"];
```

Comment: How would that look in code? no idea how to write that :(

Comment: Ahh hmm.. trying to figure out how to add and then get stats with that example for lets say Site A :)